# How to find $x^3 +2 x^2 y \pmod 7$ if $x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ and $y \equiv 5 \pmod 7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

My working so far: 
$$
x^3 \equiv 3x^2 \pmod 7
$$
$$
x^2 \equiv 3x \pmod 7
$$
$$
2y \equiv 10 \pmod 7
$$

Therefore:

$$
2x^2y \equiv 30x \pmod 7
$$
Therefore:
$$
x^3 + 2x^2y \equiv 30x + 3x^2 \pmod 7
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\pmod 7$ means the remainder when divided by $7$. So you can just go all the way and replace $x$ by $3$ to get $117\pmod 7 = 5 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \equiv b \pmod c$ then $a^p \equiv b^p \pmod c$.

So:
$$
\begin{align}
x^3 &\equiv 27 \pmod 7\\
&\equiv 6 \pmod 7\\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
x^2 &\equiv 9 \pmod 7\\
&\equiv 2 \pmod 7\\
\end{align}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{align}
x^3 + 2 x^2 y &\equiv 6 + 2 \times 2 \times 5 \pmod 7\\
&\equiv 26 \pmod 7\\
&\equiv 5 \pmod 7\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh true! Thanks very much :)